# Curve-fitting for polynomial regression model gives incorrect ouput in Python

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, polynomials, scipy-optimize

Given a dataset as follows:

```
    year  population
0   1998       12.42
1   1999       12.53
2   2000       12.63
3   2001       12.72
4   2002       12.80
5   2003       12.88
6   2004       12.96
7   2005       13.04
8   2006       13.11
9   2007       13.18
10  2008       13.25
11  2009       13.31
12  2010       13.38
13  2011       13.44
14  2012       13.51
15  2013       13.57
16  2014       13.64
17  2015       13.71
18  2016       13.79
19  2017       13.86
20  2018       13.93
21  2019       13.98
```

Based on code from [this link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/curve-fitting-with-python/),

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import arange
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

data = df.values
x, y = data[:, 0], data[:, 1]

def objective(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x + b * x ** 2 + c

popt, _ = curve_fit(objective, x, y)
a, b, c = popt
print('y = %.5f * x + %.5f * x^2 + %.5f' % (a, b, c))
pyplot.scatter(x, y)
x_line = arange(min(x), max(x), 1)
y_line = objective(x_line, a, b, c)
pyplot.plot(x_line, y_line, '--', color='red')
pyplot.show()
```

Out:

```
y = 2.58436 * x + -0.00063 * x^2 + -2654.41790
```

[image]

But when I test with `x = 2015`, so the formula will be `2.58436 * 2015 + -0.00063 * 2015^2 + -2654.41790`, it gives the result `-4.87425`, which clearly is not the correct fitting result as I expected.

Anyone could help me to figure out why I get this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula isn't correct since you rounded your coefficients to the fifth decimal place. Evaluating the objective with the exact coefficients, i.e. `objective(2015, *popt)` gives `13.723435783853802`.

Comment: Thanks, so how to fix the issue from my code?

Comment: @ahbon I don't see any issues in your code. If you want to print the coefficients a,b,c and evaluate the polynomial by hand, I'd recommend printing more decimal digits, e.g. use `%.12f` instead of `%.5f`.

Comment: Use `%.12f` make sense, it gives me answer expected. Thanks.